# Braintree payment method create issue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, braintree

I am trying to create Braintree Payment Method.

But I need to store CVV, expirationDate [but official document](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/node#expiration_month) page showing these two are deprecated.

Right now I am using code for creating Braintree Payment Method.

Example :

```
gateway.paymentMethod.create({
  customerId: req.session.passport.user.braintree_customer_id,
  paymentMethodNonce: "fake-valid-mastercard-nonce",
  cardholder_name: req.session.passport.user.first_name+" "+req.session.passport.user.last_name,
  billingAddress: {
    streetAddress: req.body.address1,
    locality:req.body.city,
    region:req.body.state,
    postalCode:req.body.zip
  },

  options: {
    verifyCard: true,
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if(err){console.log(err);return false;}
  callback(false,result)
});
```

But I need to store CC, CVV, Exp Date, Cardholder name, etc.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

You're using a payment method nonce to send the credit card details, which includes the number, cvv and expiration details. Cardholder name is not deprecated, so you can submit that separately from the nonce.

Note: CVVs are used for the initial transaction, but are not stored in the vault. In fact, there is no way to store the CVV in the vault.

Comment: Reading the above question, my initial thoughts are to tell OPs that "if you have to ask, you should not be storing credit card details at all". Purely for my curiosity, does Braintree recommend a minimum level of security/accreditation for implementers who need to (or choose to) store these sensitive details themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i  was fixed issue using

> paymentMethodNonce : nonce-from-the-client

Example Code:

```
    gateway.paymentMethod.create({
              customerId:'xxx',
               paymentMethodNonce: 'nonce-from-the-client',
               cardholder_name:'xxx' 
-----------------------------------------------------------
```